# Where to implement methods for menu item that is not window dependent (Cocoa OSX

Tags: cocoa, validation, macos, nsmenuitem

I currently implement most of the functions for my mainMenu in a NSWindowController subclass, this works fine for most functions but I would like to be able to use some menu items when no Window is selected.  Where would be the best place to implement and validate these kind of menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put those in my NSApplication delegate.